# Seeking UK Postcode out-code list containing county?

Tags: data, united-kingdom, postal-code

I’m trying to put together a spreadsheet containing the following fields: postcode out-code, county

Can anybody please point me in the direction of a list (or 2 lists which I could join) containing UK postcode out codes and county?

I need to know for which county a postcode out code is located in.

Preferably open source data.

Comment: Code-point and BoundaryLine from https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html (Great Britain only) not UK.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  If it is open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The [Office for National Statistics Postcode Directory](https://www.ons.gov.uk/methodology/geography/geographicalproducts/postcodeproducts) has postcode and county and is a downloadable dataset. Note this is the administrative county, whereas often people think in terms of the ceremonial county or even historic county. If you want either of those then Ordnance Survey produces [shape files](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/products/boundary-line.html). All open data.